# Change size tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have one table and before I get the data I do this

```
[self.TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(kRowHorizontalPadding_iPad * 0.5,     kRowVerticalPadding_iPad * 0.5, 1024 - kRowHorizontalPadding_iPad, kCellHeight_iPad)];
self.TableView.rowHeight = 500;
```

the thing is that i want to change the height and the frame once the device rotate ! but is not working I tried reloadData but still not working please help.

Comment: Read the docs on autoresizingmask

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

and

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
```

should help you. There is also

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation
```

method that might be useful when you want to work in portrait/landscape modes.

Don't forget to add UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate to your header file, just like that:

```
@interface myClassBlabla : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
  int checkInt;
}
```

Hope it helps